# Uncaught SyntaxError JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to parse a JSON string and it throws
`Uncaught SyntaxError : Unexpected token` error. Below is the content am having in a variable as a string.

> **Note :** I checked the typeof() for the jsonString variable and it returned `string`. So the variable is of string type and no doubt in
>   that

**JSON String :**

```
{"title":"This is my Title","body":"&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClassB5F21AC89A1F40D0BCA5A8DBB6F738ED&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size&amp;#58;11.0pt;font-family&amp;#58;&amp;quot;Calibri&amp;quot;,sans-serif;&quot;&gt;Our commitment to the development of this feature is
delayed  due to the unexpected JSON parse error. &amp;#160;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;","byline":"This issue is killing me now for more than 2 days.  ","tile":0,"showText":true,"showImage":true,"image":{"ImageUrl":"/Path/to/imgFolder/hero%20background.png","Hyperlink":"","OpenHyperlinkInNewWindow":false,"Alignment":"","AlternateText":"","BorderWidth":0,"Height":0,"HorizontalSpacing":0,"VerticalSpacing":0,"Width":0},"publishedDate":"/Date(1496864514000)/","labels":["Character and Values"],"peopleList":[]}
```

I couldn't identify whats the problem is. Does any one have the clue?

Based on the line and column number in the error, it shows that the unexpected character is in ending of line 1 i.e at the end of `this feature is` in line 1. So all I can guess is that the line break might be the problem. Even if the line break causes, is there any way to handle this parsing issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a hard newline in the middle of the string; depending on what the *actual* string is and how it's being retrieved/consumed/etc. this could be an issue. If the string appears in a source file it's not legal.

Comment: Your json string is not valid, put it in [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) for example and see it for yourself

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree with the line break. But this is how i get data from the backend. Actually, the contents in the rich text field is converted to JSON string in backend and sent back to client side. So this is how I get the string

Comment: Fix the backend. it is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a linebreak with your JSON.body after delayed.

```
 ..... feature is <--- THERE IS A LINEBREAK HERE
delayed  .....
```

This is not a valid JSON character and shall be defined as **\n**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with the line break. But this is how i get data from the backend. Actually, the contents in the rich text field is converted to JSON string in backend and sent back to client side. So this is how I get the string

Comment: so you need to correct the backend as your return is not a valid JSON format ;) Please do not hesitate to upvote for the correct response

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON. With fixed newlines it looks like:

```
{
    "title": "This is my Title",
    "body": "&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClassB5F21AC89A1F40D0BCA5A8DBB6F738ED&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size&amp;#58;11.0pt;font-family&amp;#58;&amp;quot;Calibri&amp;quot;,sans-serif;&quot;&gt;Our commitment to the development of this feature is delayed due to the unexpected JSON parse error. & amp;#160;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;",
    "byline": "This issue is killing me now for more than 2 days.  ",
    "tile": 0,
    "showText": true,
    "showImage": true,
    "image": {
        "ImageUrl": "/Path/to/imgFolder/hero%20background.png",
        "Hyperlink": "",
        "OpenHyperlinkInNewWindow": false,
        "Alignment": "",
        "AlternateText": "",
        "BorderWidth": 0,
        "Height": 0,
        "HorizontalSpacing": 0,
        "VerticalSpacing": 0,
        "Width": 0
    },
    "publishedDate": "/Date(1496864514000)/",
    "labels": ["Character and Values"],
    "peopleList": []
}
```

Comment: Agree, JsonLint is great for these kind of things. Took a quick look myself, removed the newlines and it's valid and good to go.

Comment: Weird now it is correct, first it was giving the error shown in my answer

Comment: I agree with the line break. But this is how i get data from the backend. Actually, the contents in the rich text field is converted to JSON string in backend and sent back to client side. So this is how I get the string.

Comment: With the line breaks it is not a JSON string, but just a string with a line break. The JSON format dictates a certain format, especially without line breaks. Otherwise your data isn't parseable. You have to fix this in the backend first before you can use it in the frontend.